# CSS Dropdown Menu - Sub Menu Hover Text Color Inheritance

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been working on a css dropdown menu but am struggling with the sub menu text color.

As expected, the sub menu background color remains in the hover color but the text reverts back to the non-hover state.

For example, when hovering Item 9 I need the text in "Menu, Item 3 and Item 6" to be the same (white) as Item 9.

I am thinking that it is an inheritance issue but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the CSS

```
.clearboth {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
}
#nav {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 1.0;
}
#nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
#nav a:link {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:visited {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    left: -1px;
}
#nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}
#nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}
#nav li.menu {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav li.menu:hover {
    background-color: #66a3e0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav li li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav li:hover {
    background-color: #66a3e0;
    color: white; /* No effect. Inheritance? */
}
#nav li li:hover {
    background-color: #66a3e0;
    color: white; /* No effect. Inheritance? */
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
.right-arrow {
    float: right;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3<span class="right-arrow">&#9658;</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 6<span class="right-arrow">&#9658;</span></a>  
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Item 7</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 8</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Item 9</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clearboth" />
</div>
```

Any help, ideas or other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/tinkering/WD7xY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover > a:link, #nav li:hover > a:visited{
    color:white;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EB97N/

Comment: Thank you. There is a bit of a problem with IOS for iphone and iPad (latest is ver 7.2) and transparency between the list elements. But I believe it is a Safari bug. IOS for Mac is fine. Otherwise it works really well. Thanks again.